# Enterprise Architect Source Import warns that string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am importing C# source code of a fairly large solution into Enterprise Architect backed by a SQL Database and I am getting repeatedly for one specific type being imported a message box saying

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server [-2147217833]: String or binary data would be truncated.

It there an easy way to figure out what exactly makes it fail?

**Edit**

As pointed out by Geert I looked into the `DBError.txt` and the content of it was more or less

```
Context:
  Update t_connector SET 
    ... DestElement='List<Some_Really_Very_Very_Long_Type_Name_With_Subclass>' ...
```

I then looked into the DB scheme and there I searched for the declaration of the respective column which turned out to be

```
DestElement (nvarchar(50), null)
```

Can I simply modify the column definition so that it can take say 100 characters or would that break my EA?

Comment: You better not change the database structure of EA. Although it will probably not crash, you won't be able to transfer to another model, and you might run into problem when doing xmi import/export. What you can do, is report it as a bug to Sparx. They can then make sure the reverse engineering process doesn't choke on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is the `DBError.txt` file. You can find that at `%appdata%\Sparx Systems\EA`

Often you can find in that file the offending SQL statement, and use that to figure out what went wrong.

If that doesn't help you can start a profiler on the SQL Server, import the code until you get the error, and then check what the last insert/update statement was.

If I had to guess it is probably a name for a class, property, operation or parameter that exceeds 255 characters, or maybe some comments that are very large.

Most name fields in EA are limited to 255 characters. Notes fields are generally (almost) unlimited.